# loop through alphabet and add ID to A tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four a tags without an ID wrapped in a div

```
<div class = "comTabs">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

i would like to name the a tag Ids using a for loop of the letters of the alphabet in descending order

```
<div class = "comTabs">
  <a id = "A"></a>
  <a id = "B"></a>
  <a id = "C"></a>
  <a id = "D"></a>
</div>
```

here is my JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < ($('.commTabs a').length); i++) {
var $elem = $('.commTabs > a')[i];
```

*here is where its going wrong, all the A tag IDs are defined as "Z"*

```
for (var letter = 65; letter <= 90; letter++) {
$($elem).each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', String.fromCharCode(letter));
  });
}}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Yea I just saw that, not sure if you noticed, but you have a regular for loop then the each loop inside of the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it directly like below using `$('.comTabs a').each(function(i){`:-

Example:-

```js
$('.comTabs a').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', String.fromCharCode(65 + i));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "comTabs">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <a>4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ethan E  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 3):

Your mixing two loops together in your example code, simplify it by just using one. I'll use `.each` here

```
$('.commTabs a').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', String.fromCharCode(65 + i));
});
```

Comment: i need the first loop to define $elem

Comment: this returns each a tag ID as "A"

Comment: @AlivetoDie yeah, just edited, which is similar to yours. Kudos.

Comment: @Alive to Die thanks man! so simple kicking myself how i did not see that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = 65;
$('.commTabs > a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', String.fromCharCode(letter));
    i++;
  });
}}
```